# Is it possible to create a dynamic module with a custom `__dict__` class?

Tags: python, import, python-importlib

When doing `module = types.ModuleType('mymodule')`, we don't get any chance of doing further customization, and we can't override `module.__dict__` since it's readonly...

The same seems to apply with all other `importlib` functions (`module_from_spec` alike)

Is there a way of doing it which is not too much dirty (like... sub-classing ModuleType, and creating a temporary module and copying the fields...) ?